# disable password prompt on user switch?

Tags: 11.10, lock-screen

I've got 11.10 on a desktop machine with two users. Both users have "Password" set to "Not asked on login" in Users Settings. At startup, either user can log in without a password. But once both users are logged in, it takes a password to switch between users.

In previous Ubuntus, you could override this by setting /desktop/gnome/lockdown/disable_lock_screen to True in gconf-editor. That is ignored in the Gnome 3 / Unity era.

Does anyone know a way to disable the password prompt when switching between users in Oneiric?

Answer (score 3):

Only this worked out for me:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen 'true'
```

This disables screen lock on user switch and hibernation wakeup.

PS: gsettings has to be configured for every user seperately.

Comment: Of the various answers, this is the only one that worked (12.04). Even Users and Groups (gnome-system-tools) couldn't do this. (It allows the setting, but has no effect.) Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 2):

Run this command:

```
sudo visudo
```

Then, at the end add this line:

```
user   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/su
```

This will disable the password check for the "su" command for the specified user.

cheers

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Still password prompt. However, if you choose "Switch User Account" instead, and then select another user from the startup screen, then you gen logged in without password prompt. What is my problem?